# Can i ask a question about a website's preferences, specifically Youtube?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question is about disabling Youtube's HTML5 video auto-playing. it takes more than an add-on on Chrome since none of them are working and i don't use Chrome. is it okay to ask that kind of question on Super User or will it be considered off-topic?

Comment: Yes; Considering this is done through your Google Account's YouTube preferences it would indeed not be on topic.

Comment: Personally I think this would be on topic at [webapps.se] rather than here. I'd make sure to check their help centre to see though. Hopefully someone else could confirm.

Comment: Well there is no option in my Youtube's account settings for that, i'll post my question on Web Applications then, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For YouTube, and most other web apps and websites, asking about preferences, account related issues, or anything like that, [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) would be the better/proper place to ask.